# std::vector::insert vs std::list::operator[]

Tags: c++, list, vector

I know that `std::list::operator[]` is not implemented as it has bad performance. But what about `std::vector::insert` it is as much inefficient as much `std::list::operator[]` is. What is the explanation behind?

Comment: "it is as much inefficient" that really depends, but it isn't something that can just be assumed.

Comment: "it is as much inefficient " - *highly speculative* and entirely dependent on scenario of usage. Your question would be served well to demonstrate where that is indeed the case.

Comment: For `std::list::operator[]`, you can do it by yourself if you really want, for `std::vector::insert`, you can't.

Comment: Both methods can be used arbitrary. So I don't see a point to discuss them for some specific case. But for one of them implementation is considered inappropriate. Why?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Your assertions are extremely unhelpful. You must know that they're wrong. You can't be unaware that they're balderdash. Anyway, for other readers: both `vector::insert` and a hypothetical `list::operator[]` would in general have O(*n*) complexity in the size *n* of the container. The indexing operator could however be optimized for sequential access. The vector's effective requirement of direct indexing of a raw array makes sequential inserts optimization probably impossible.

Comment: @Narek: If it makes you feel better, IMO std::list should have `operator[]`. :)

Comment: @GManNickG IMO `std::list` should have `.at()` not `operator[]`.  Methods look (possibly) expensive, operators look cheap.  In particular, barring overloading it, all uses of `[]` are cheap, and thus making an expensive `[]` violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @Yakk I disagree, if a container implements `at` then it should also implement `operator[]` as the former is supposed to be a bounds-checking implementation of the latter - to exclude either the non-bounds-checking or bounds-checking methods would not be in keeping with standard containers.

Comment: @Yakk: My comments below regarding "cheapness" apply; I don't think there is any intuitive cutoff for why O(n) is not cheap but O(lg n) is. Maybe O(n^3) or O(2^n) is a better "cheapness" cutoff? If I'm using a list, I'm aware of or can look up the runtime characteristics of the operations available to me. At that point all I want is my standard library to take away boilerplate code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Obviously the complexity of both is n,, but the statement "is as much inefficient" is nebulous at best. Had Narek simply said, "both have linear complexity" (as *you* correctly clarified, perhaps because it wasn't said?) I wouldn't have said a thing; he didn't. I found your comment much more clarifying than the question itself, and up-ticked it, despite the lashing. Freudenstadt ftw.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury On a `std::list`, bounds-checking is going to have rounding-error performance costs: node-based iteration is *slow* compared to branches.  It is not in keeping with standard containers for `[]` or `at` to be on linear-or-higher cost containers *at all*, so any change is goingto not be in keeping with standard containers.  In any case, if your position is we cannot have `at` without `[]`, my position is we should not have a linear `[]`, so you are stuck with `*std::next( foo.begin(), n )`.

Comment: @GManNickG O(n) is exponentially more expensive than O(lg n) as n grows.  O(lg n) <= k lg n operations on a 64 bit system never grows to more than k 64 operations.  On the same system, O(n) <= k n operations never grows to more than k 10^20 operations.  If you cannot see any kind of significant difference there I'm not sure what to say.  I'll admit that an O( (lg n)^10 ) algorithm would be fuzzy (is it fast or slow?), but that isn't in question. I'm aware that O-notation is about change in speed as n grows. I could use convoluted wording to cover that, but I assume you can provide your own.

Comment: @Yakk: I know the difference, I'm just not sure why we need to artificially limit `operator[]` to some "acceptable" runtime. When I use a SAT solver I don't have to sign a contract saying I understand it's 2^n in the worst case, I just use it because it's the right tool for me. If I need to do a one-off lookup in a linked list, `operator[]` or `at` would have been useful.

Comment: @GManNickG Because operators, barring a good reason, should behave like they do on primitive types.  `[]` on primitive types is fast.  A linear-time slow `[]` would violate this principle of least surprise by being increadibly slow on medium to large size `n`.  The task can be done without `[]`, `[]` is just sugar, and sugar for something that doesn't behave like `[]` on arrays or pointers in such an important dimension in such a large way is a bad idea.  Barring, again, a good reason.  Which I haven't seen.  Type `*std::next( l.begin(), n )` if you want to get the nth element in linear time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::vector::insert` is implemented because `std::vector` has to meet requirements of [SequenceContainer concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer), while `operator[]` is not required by any concepts (that I know of), possible that will be added in `ContiguousContainer` concept in c++17. So `operator[]` added to containers that can be used like arrays, while `insert` is required by interface specification, so containers that meet certain concept can be used in generic algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I think Slava's answer does the best job, but I'd like to offer a supplementary explanation. Generally with data structures, it's far more common to have more accesses than insertions, than vice versa. There are many data structures that may try to optimize access at the cost of insertion, but the inverse is much more rare, because it tends to be less useful in real life.

`operator[]`, if implemented for a linked list, would access an existing value presumably (similar to how it does for `vector`). `insert` adds new values. It's much more likely you will be willing to take a big performance hit to insert some new elements into a `vector`, provided that the subsequent accesses are extremely fast. In many cases, element insertion may be outside of the critical path entirely whereas the critical path consists of a single traversal, or random access of already-present data. So it's simply convenient to have `insert` take care of the details for you in that case (it's actually a bit annoying to write efficiently and correctly). This is actually a not-uncommon use of a vector.

On the other hand, using `operator[]` on a linked list would almost always be a sign that you are using the wrong data structure.

Comment: "operator[] always accesses an existing value." Not for a `std::map`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I've qualified my statement about operator[] more carefully, thank you. I don't think it really changes the substance of my answer though.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice answer now. UV'd.

Answer (score 1):

`std::list::operator[]` would require an O(N) traversal and is not really in accordance with what a `list` is designed to do. If you need `operator[]` then use a different container type. When C++ folk see a `[]` they *assume* an O(1) (or, at worse, an O(Log N)) operation. Supplying `[]` for a `list` would break that.

But although `std::vector::insert` is *also* O(N), it *can* be optimised: an at-end insertion can be readily optimised by having the `vector`'s capacity grow in large chunks. An insertion in the middle requires an element-by-element move, but that again can be performed very quickly on modern chipsets.

Comment: If you want to insert at the end, then use `push_back`, you don't need `insert`, or I have missed your point?

Comment: Indeed you could use `push_back`; and the similar optimisations to at-end insertion apply.

Comment: So we don't need `insert`?

Comment: It's a bit hard to `push_back` in the *middle* of a `vector` ;-) Plus insertion allows for more than one element.

Comment: We do if we want to insert multiple elements in one line.

Comment: @Bathsheba insertion in the middle? Very efficient?

Comment: @NathanOliver what you mean insear element i one line?

Comment: I find the comment about optimization misleading, since it's the list's indexing operator that can be readily optimized, while vector inserts probably can't be, and since the growing by large chunks is what a vector does anyway.

Comment: @Narek If you want to insert multiple elements at the end of the vector `insert` will let you do that with one line of code where you would need a loop to do that with `push_back`.  You are always going to have a loop but at least with `insert` it is done for you(less code to get wrong).

Comment: @Narek you should read these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array .  These discuss the pros and cons of using a Linked List and a Vector (Dynamic array) in terms of performance.

Comment: @Narek: Yes it can be. Shifting subsequent elements is little more than a "memmove", which is *very* quick on modern chipsets.

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. Insertion in the middle is always O(N), exactly like `list::operator[]`. Insertion at the end is faster, but insertion's interface is much more general than that, so that's irrelevant. If it can "be performed quickly on many platforms", you are basically saying that despite both being O(N), insertion in the middle of a vector has better constants, and so this should be emphasized if you think this is the answer.

Comment: @NirFriedman: I'm saying exactly that. I've tidied up the answer, a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` operator is inherited from plain arrays. It has always been understood as a fast (sub linear time) accessor of the underlying container. Since list is does not support sub linear time access, it does not make sense for it to implement the operator.

```
auto a = Container [10]; // Ideally I can assume this is quick
```

The equivalent of your `std::list <>::operator []` is `std::next <std::list<>::iterator>`. Documented at [cpp-reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

```
auto a = *std::next (Container.begin (), 10); // This may take a little while
```

This is the truly generic way index a container. If the container supports random access, it will be constant time, other wise it will be linear.

Comment: Re "Since list is does not support constant time random access", no, e.g. `std::map` provides indexing operator with logarithmic complexity, so that argument does not hold water. At all.

Comment: Also, the sketched equivalence (and the assertion that it *is* an equivalence) is ungood. If `std::list` provided indexing it would most likely be optimized for sequential access.

Comment: **−1** "If the container supports random access, it will be constant time, other wise it will be linear." is Plain Wrong™.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the DV. The C++ standard library should **never** allow `[]` for O(N), although O(Log N) is permitted. UV'd.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Why not? How is O(lg n) any less arbitrary?

Comment: @GManNickG: Because it's a damn sight quicker. Remember the log10 of the number of particles in the universe is only 87. O(Log N) ain't that bad.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I know what lg means. You know what's a damn sight quicker than lg n? log* n. So maybe the standard library should only allow that. My point is that your cutoff is completely arbitrary.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you are right about the assumtion of operation [] to be constant time, but I think the general rational to be correct, on the other hand I believe my statements about std::advance are correct.

Comment: You use `advance()` where you meant to use `next()`. The former is void and takes a non-const lvalue reference...

Comment: @nate: I believe that if `std::list` had an indexing operator it would not only be optimized for sequential access, but would be guaranteed O(1) for sequential access after an initial O(n) positioning. Otherwise it would have no real advantage over your suggested alternative. Which therefore is not an equivalence.

Comment: This is one for after dinner conversations, but IMHO O(log N) for `[]` is the limit.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf what you suggest would require keeping a "last indexed position" cache within the list, which would bloat it for all cases only to optimize one specific case that could very easily be done outside by not throwing away the iterator you got from your initial search.

Comment: @nate: A `std::list` has lots of pointers inside. Not much bloat.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf in msvc its two pointers and a size, what you suggest would require another pointer and another size, increasing it by 60%, thats not alot of bloat for something of very little value?

Comment: The percentage you cite is against the object size. But a `std::list` with even one item has a dynamically allocated chunk of memory with associated overhead in the heap structures. One pointer and size in the object is insignificant compared to the overhead of that.

Comment: There are allocators with an effective overhead of zero. And I could be storing `char`s

Comment: @nate All allocators would be zero overhead if that was possible for a general allocator. It isn't. I think you may be thinking of a free list. It doesn't apply. About the second point, for a `std::list<char>`, each item contains necessarily a `char` and two pointers, which (together with the heap overhead, which comes on top) makes the overhead tremendous.

Comment: With some serious limitations, I can create an allocator that's only overhead is one pointer shared by all allocations.